# How do I upload the .mdf file and associated .ldf file from visual studio to a host using WebsitePanel?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, hosting

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 3 project in Visual Studio and the database is a SQL Server Express database BeerRecommenderContext.mdf with a log file BeerRecommenderContext.ldf. I can upload these to the standard App_Data directory but the connection string doesn't seem to work. I think it's because my host doesn't recognize the files as SQL Server files. My host, dotnet-host.com is using WebsitePanel. My current connection string is

```
Server=mssql0921.dotnet-host.com;Database=BeerRecommenderContext;UserID=timoteo1097;Password=●●●●●●●●
```

(of course the password is actually filled in properly)

Answer (score 0):

If you have stand alone .mdf & .ldf files in your data directory then you probably need to use the `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;` in your connection string.

Your connection string is currently pointing at a different server which wont pick up anything in your `App_Data` folder.

If you can access the database server at your hosting via SQL Server Management Studio then it may be better to move all the data from your standalone files and use the database provided by the hosting company.

Comment: When I use the following connection string to point to my .mdf file in the App_Data folder, it doesn't work either: data source=C:\HostingSpaces\brewsfor\brewsforme.com\wwwroot\App_Data;Integrated Security=SSPI;
         database=BeerRecommenderContext.mdf;
         AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|BeerRecommenderContext.mdf;
         User Instance=true"

I tried doing what you said and used the database provided by the hosting company with the string in the original question and that didn't work either. It seems like that should be the way to go.

Comment: The name may have been part of the problem. I've actually given up on this host switched to another host that works normally. Thank you for your help.